# How can i cache an access token embedded in a redirect url?

Tags: http, flutter, dart, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make use of an API from a local bank, which uses OAuth2 as their authorization method. 
The authentication process is as follows: 
User clicks on button, webview within application is launched, and user is directed to
URL A: "https://{API URL}/{constant key}/{redirect url}"
Then they have to authenticate with their banking credentials, and the next page prompts them to key in an OTP.
If this is successful, the session token will be embedded in the redirect url as such:
Redirect URL: https://{redirect url}/{access token}/{type}

How can I cache or store this access token as a variable in my flutter code so that i can use it for other API calls? I am currently using flutter webview plugin and i have no issues launching the webview and reaching the different URLs, but i can't seem to find a method to store the token.

Answer (score 0):

*For local storage:*

You can use **https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences** which uses the native counterparts for storing preferences. Its basically a key/value store.

> Wraps NSUserDefaults (on iOS) and SharedPreferences (on Android),
>   providing a persistent store for simple data. Data is persisted to
>   disk asynchronously. Neither platform can guarantee that writes will
>   be persisted to disk after returning and this plugin must not be used
>   for storing critical data.

Another alternative would be SQLite with this package: **https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite**

> SQLite plugin for Flutter. Supports both iOS and Android.

You can of course also use the File I/O capabilities of Flutter as described in the docs:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Another route is by using a cache manager package, which will use the cache of the app together with SQLlite in the background. Might also be a solution but files can be deleted by the OS at any point in time. See the package at: **https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager**

*for remote storage:*

Then of course, as most of the flutter developers use firestore (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or cloud storage (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) from the Firebase Brand, you can easily chose to go this way. Of course then the data would be in the cloud. Dont know if that meets your security requirements.

Most likely i would prefer going the local persistence way with the first mentioned methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't really point towards any methods that allows for the retrieval of a token embedded in the url